# Listen to changes from a function in workmanager flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, background-service

I am performing a background task of uploading videos in my flutter app. I want to display the progress of completion on my ui.

I was using a valuenotifier before implementing workmanager, and it was updating my ui. But after using workmanager, it isn't.

My code:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point') // Mandatory if the App is obfuscated or using Flutter 3.1+
void callbackDispatcher() {
  print("Running callback dispatcher");
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    if(inputData!=null) {
      print("Task started");
      await uploadVideos(uploadVideoData: UploadVideoData.fromJson(inputData));
      print("Task completed");
    }
    else {
      //TODO:
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}



await Workmanager().initialize(
      callbackDispatcher, // The top level function, aka callbackDispatcher
      isInDebugMode: true // If enabled it will post a notification whenever the task is running. Handy for debugging tasks
  );
  String uniqueId = '${uploadVideoData.rId}_${uploadVideoData.pId}_${uploadVideoData.groupId}';
  await Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(uniqueId, uniqueId, inputData: uploadVideoData.toJson());
```

The function `callbackDispatcher` is a top level main function, declared outside in main.dart.

In the uploadVideos function, I was updating the value like this:

```
.......
uploadPercent.value = 0;
.......
....... 
    await uploadAsset(
            rid: uploadVideoData?.rId ?? 0,
            grpId: uploadVideoData?.groupId ?? 0,
            pId: uploadVideoData?.pId ?? 0,
            asset: File(compressedVideoPath),
            onChanged: (percent) {
              if(uploadVideoData?.fromGallery==true) {
                uploadPercent.value = ((percent * 100) / 2) + 50;
              }
              else {
                uploadPercent.value = percent*100;
              }
              debugPrint('Uploading percent is: $percent');
            });
.......
.......
.......
```

Upload percent is defined like this in top level in main:

```
ValueNotifier<double> uploadPercent = ValueNotifier(0);
```

Also, before and after the `uploadAsset` function, I am updating some values in my provider variable. For example:

```
videoUploadingProvider.currentUpdate = uniqueId;
```

This videoUploadingProvider is also defined in top level, outside in `main.dart.`

```
VideoProvider videoUploadingProvider = VideoProvider();
```

These all were working when I was directly using `uploadVideos`, instead of calling it in `Workmanager().executeTask`.

How to fix this?